# Linux CPU/Memory Load Graph

Tags: linux, graph, load, cpu-usage

I am working on a project and testing it on Linux.
In my report I want to present a diagram for CPU/Memory load of the machine!

What is the best method to obtain these data!?
Should i write a bash script to periodically check this (e.g. reading /proc/stat)? does not this script produce load itself? 
any lightweight script or program available?

Comment: What raw data did you generate? What type of diagram do you want?

Comment: Does your distro not have http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/)(fork of Nagios) to monitor CPU/Memory load. Both support graphs on the parameters monitored. Both have plugins to easily monitor CPU/Memory usage.
Setting up nagios on a linux machine via the package manager is pretty straight forward. Icinga supports automatic PDF reports generation, that also contain the graphics for the parameters monitored.
Icinga provides a [virtual appliance](https://www.icinga.org/2010/09/22/starter-kit-icinga-virtual-appliance/) - so it's pretty easy to setup.

Comment: Nice, but i do not have access to graphic desktop, just shell!:( so i think i should make the graph manually myself!

Comment: those are running in apache, so graphs are in the browser. I am not sure how important your monitoring is, those monitoring tools might be an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I would use munin, it is very easy to install and part of most linux distros repositories, you can use that of course for grouping graphs from many servers together...